# 'Unable to read symbols' error

Tags: iphone, xcode, console

When I 'Build and Go' on the device, the console shows:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/Steve/Blue/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Blue.app/Blue" (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols for ""/Users/Steve/Blue/build/Debug-iphoneos"/Blue.app/Blue" (file not found).
```

Is this something I should worry about? If so, where should I look to find the root of the issue? The app works OK, but I'm just worried that this might be an AppStore approval issue.

Comment: Which iPhone SDK are we talking about? If it's 3.0 that's under NDA. Better resort to if SDK 3.0 devforums.apple.com

Comment: Same problem here as well with xcode 3.4.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838949/unable-to-read-symbols-for-developer-platforms-iphoneos-platform-devicesupport

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer per se, but it may provide more clues and additional ammo.

I'm getting this exact same warning - twice - as well, and only for "Device - 3.0 | Debug" builds. When using the Simulator, no such warnings occur.

In my case, the message reads like yours, in a way that suggests something is being placed in one too many sets of quotes:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
> ""/Users/jdandrea/path/to/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos"/MyApp.app/MyApp"
> (file not found).
>
> warning: Unable to read symbols for
> ""/Users/jdandrea/path/to/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos"/MyApp.app/MyApp"
> (file not found).

It's as if, somewhere, "/Users/jdandrea/path/to/MyApp/build/Debug-iphoneos" exists with explicit quotes, but where?

Also, the debug target settings *do* have "Generate Debug Symbols" checked.

Also also, I have two global breakpoints: [NSException raise] and objc_exception_throw. If I disable these, I still get the above message. Then again, if I *enable* them, I (sometimes?) get this:

> warning: Couldn't raise load state for
> requested shlib: "libobjc.A.dylib" for
> breakpoint 1.
>
> warning: Couldn't raise load state for
> requested shlib: "CoreFoundation" for
> breakpoint 2.

This was all added to a stock Cocoa Touch app. I keep looking around the target settings and the codebase, but I'm not sure what's amiss. Even Instruments and other analyses aren't complaining about leaks.

(I mention this second part about the breakpoints on the off chance that it's related. If not, then that's a separate issue. Again, it only shows up when debugging on the device.)

In short, I'm stumped too. Hopefully this helps provide someone with more clues to help crack the case!

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is super old, but I'd like to share what worked for me - hopefully it will help someone reading this in the future.

It was just a matter of removing a space in the path to the application. The thing is, you can't see where the space is in the console - it cuts it off at the space. You will have to manually look through your path for that rogue space!

Console might show you something like:

```
users/yourname/desktop/my/myapp.app/
```

When your path actually looks like this:

```
users/yourname/desktop/my app/myapp.app/
```

Remove the space (or add an underscore) and make it:

```
users/yourname/desktop/my_app/myapp.app/
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

This appears to be a complaint of a missing file. If you haven't tried already you will want to Clean the project (Shift-Command-K) and then build it again. Although I doubt the App store would reject your app for this reason, it is rarely a best practice to release an App with build warnings so you will want to resolve this prior to submission.

Comment: This is not a build warning it is a warning output to the console when the app runs.