# Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, ios4

I am getting following error when I am running my application on iPod touch (version 4.2.1). My app crashes after a point:

`Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1 (8C148)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).`

My XCODE version is 3.2.6 with IOS 4.3 and my deployment target version is 4.2.

Any reason why this is so happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I have similar problems, and what works for me is **Clean** and **Build** the target again (without any changes in code!). Strange, but sometimes I had to do it more than once.

Comment: It works that way but then I am not able to see some of the images in my app. Also, it crashes if I try to run by tapping on app icon in the device. So, I had to run it from the XCODE and that too with multiple clean and build. Any clue?

Comment: I'm afraid it's too wide spectrum of possible causes to tell. Depends on how you load/display images. For crash, try debugging techniques like catching objc_exception_throw and/or ask more detailed question on SO.

Answer (score 5):

Just delete that folder (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2.1), connect your device again, go to the XCode Organizer and it will ask you to collect the symbols from the device. After a couple minutes it will be done collecting and processing the symbols off the device, and you should be good to go.

You can also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284277/libxcodedebuggersupport-dylib-is-missing-in-ios-4-2-1-development-sdk) for more solutions if this doesn't work.

Comment: I did that but it is still not working. Surprisingly, It was working before and suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason just got this in XCODE 4.2.  Had to go to

TARGET / BUILD SETTINGS / ALL / SEARCH PATHS / Library Search Paths

And remove the line that somehow had similar entry in the line.  Removed it and all is ok