# Unable to read symbols warning after updating to 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I just updated my device to iOS 4.3.3. Xcode 4 automatically updated when I plugged in my iPhone4 first time after iOS update.

When running my project I get a warning now:

> warning: Unable to read symbols for
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3
>   (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
>   (file not found).

Why do I get this warning and how to solve this?

Comment: did you update xcode to 4.3.3?

Comment: Yes it did update automatically

Comment: I've started getting a similar warning, and fetching the symbols from my device didn't help: warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit (file not found).
warning: Tried to remove a non-existent library: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838949/unable-to-read-symbols-for-developer-platforms-iphoneos-platform-devicesupport-4?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also faced  this issue you should just delete that folder (/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport//4.3.3), connect your device again, go to the XCode Organizer and it will ask you to collect the symbols from the device. After a couple minutes it will be done collecting and processing the symbols off the device, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried but failed. Xcode3.2.6 with ios 4.3.3.Then how can fix it? anyway else?

Comment: Delete the app from your device.. restart the device .. restart your mac... delete above mentioned folder and also similar folders and connect your device with your mac and collect the symbols again.. hope it will help

Comment: Does not help. iOS 4.3.3 sends two compressed files over, then they're unpacked ... and the AccessibilityBundles folder simply isn't in there. For me it isn't the location of DeviceSupport that's an issue. That part is fine. It's that some folders underneath THAT are missing, even if you toss it and re-fetch the whole thing. :(

Answer (score 1):

As I've read elsewhere, making a symlink can take care of the problem. I had no success with refetching symbols from my ipad. This probably isn't the best solution, but it's working so far for me.

just run:

```
sudo ln  -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/Developer/
 /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J2)/Symbols/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

You should open Organizer( Xcode > Window > Organizer ) and do something like "fetch symbols" I think when your phone is plugged in.